# Ubuntu: How to link a binary

Tags: linux, ubuntu, binaryfiles

I have a C++ code. I compiled it and I now have the binary xyz. Now everytime I need to execute the binary, I had to switch to the corresponding directory to execute it using ./xyz But how do I run the binary using a command say xyz from anywhere. How do I link this binary to a command in ubuntu. I currently use Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ubuntu sets your PATH environment variable to include `~/bin`. So the easiest way to make `xyz` executable from anywhere is move `xyz` to `~/bin`, or to make a symlink from ~/bin to the `xyz`'s directory:

```
ln -s /path/to/xyz/directory/ ~/bin
```

Or, you could [add `/path/to/xyz/directory/` to your PATH](http://opencheese.com/2009/05/11/ubuntu-how-to-add-a-path-to-your-path-list-in-terminal-bashrc-file/) environment variable.

Comment: Thank you. I did it by adding to PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Ubuntu doesn't know where to look for binary xyz.

You need to either add a path to your shell profile (it'll tell your shell where to look for programs like xyz) or add xyz to a directory that's already included in your path.

For example, /usr/bin is one place where binaries are stored normally. However, I'm not entirely sure what the generally accepted place to install new binaries is (/usr/bin might be generally reserved for system binaries).

Ubuntu by default uses a bash shell. In your home directory (~), you can check/edit your .profile file and either edit or see what directories are added to your PATH variable.

Comment: yes you are correct. But do you know how to add the path to my binary xyz.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. You're trying to run "xyz" without having to cd to the directory and use "./xyz", correct?

Comment: Yes thats correct. And I found it. I did `export PATH=$PATH:/xyz_location` and now its working. Thanks Poff

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/` is the right place to install locally-compiled binaries for systemwide use.  For a single user, `$HOME/bin`.