# PHPUnit , PEAR upgrading Errors

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpunit, pear

Note : I've read **all questions about this problem**

PEAR is installed and configured on my system (Ubuntu 11.10 + Apache/2.2.20). Because

```
<?php
require_once 'System.php';
var_dump(class_exists('System', false));
?>
```

Returning this :

```
bool(true)
```

([PEAR Manual : Checking if PEAR works Step 4](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php))

When i tried to use phpunit i'm getting this error.

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 38
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 38
```

After this error i've decided to install it

```
sudo /usr/bin/pear install phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage
```

But i'm getting

```
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.4), installed version is 1.9.2
```

I'm getting this error when upgrading PEAR with `sudo pear upgrade`

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PEAR_Registry::packageinfo() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Dependency2.php on line 687
```

I'm not sure what is the problem ?

**ADDITIONAL**

(`command` : `result`)

`/usr/bin/pear config-get php_dir` : `/usr/share/php`

`Configuration File (php.ini) Path (on phpinfo();)` : `/etc/php5/apache2`

`php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini -r 'echo get_include_path()."\n";'` : `.:/usr/share/php`

`pear upgrade pear` : `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PEAR_Registry::packageinfo() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Dependency2.php on line 687`

PEAR Version : 1.9.2  and `php-pear` package installed.

Comment: Whats your current PEAR version? Also did you install `php-pear` with apt-get or did you do a manual install?

Comment: PEAR Version : 1.9.2 . I've installed php-pear

Comment: @cweiske ,  `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PEAR_Registry::packageinfo() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Dependency2.php on line 687`

Comment: @Eray: I published an article on how to install PHPUnit without PEAR. Take a look and see if will help you get PHPUnit going again, either way can you let me know what you thought? If it worked I'd like to post as an answer to your question. http://melikedev.com/2012/01/25/php-phpunit-use-phpunit-without-pear/

Answer (score 9):

PEAR 1.9.2 is outdated and broken beyond any hope of repair with newer pear server infrastructure.

I have no clue why distributions still insist on something that is just broken :)

[**`Install a new pear via go-pear.phar`**](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php) and make sure you have `pear version 1.9.4` and then force pear to ignore it's old cache files using

```
sudo pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/phpunit
```

---

#### Getting rid of the old pear:

```
sudo apt-get purge php5-pear
```

Now

```
which pear
```

should result in the command not being found. If it is still there delete the binary and the associated php classes in /usr/share/php.

From your console history I'd say you didn't install the new pear with **`sudo`** rights so it landed in /home/ or in /usr/local/ instead of in the default system location.

It shouldn't matter as long as you

- Get rid of the old pear
- Change your php.ini include_path to the new pear install location

Comment: I'm getting `Unknown Role class: "PEAR_Installer_Role_Pear_Installer_role_php` error while installing PEAR. You can check here : http://pastebin.com/jkH4AAkJ as you can see version still 1.9.2

Comment: You're hitting http://stackoverflow.com/a/6596669/282601 - remove php-pear first.

Comment: @cweiske , it's not solve my problem. Because , `dpkg -L php-pear` and `pear config-get php_dir` are both same, pointing to `/usr/share/php`

Comment: @cweiske no i executed this command : `apt-get remove php-pear` . And then installed a new pear via *go-pear.phar* but this it's installed to `/home/eray/pear/bin/pear` . I'm really confused, totally.

Comment: @Eray Expanded a little on the answer

Comment: @edorian i removed my old pear installation (*php5-pear*), yesterday. I record a little screencast. Can you watch this : http://screenr.com/Ebas **notice** this error on last screen : `** WARNING! Old version found at /usr/bin, please remove it or be sure to use the new /usr/bin/pear command`

Comment: @Eray That error message is just complaining that there is already a pear executable in your path. Simply do a `rm /usr/bin/pear` to zap the old executable then perform the same reinstall steps and you won't receive the warning.

Comment: @Eray you might try the answer I just posted in its entirety and let me know if you still have issues from there ...

Answer (score 3):

It can be difficult to troubleshoot for a specific environment ... but, here goes ...

I've had issues when not using the actual `pear.phpunit.de` channel to install PHPUnit, **especially** when trying to use a package manager like apt-get or yum. First, you need to be sure your pear installation is up to date. Kill the existing install from your package manager:

- sudo apt-get purge php5-pear

Then make sure you delete the executable binary file if it still exists. This is probably */usr/bin/pear*, but you may need to modify the path based on your environment:

- rm /usr/bin/pear

Next install the new pear by downloading go-pear.phar and executing it. *Make sure you install it with sudo rights (or as root) so that it is installed in the correct location*:

- wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
- sudo php go-pear.phar

You can then verify that pear works by executing the next command. If so, you'll get a list of commands:

- pear help

Finally, upgrade pear (just in case -- you did just get the latest version using go-pear.phar, after all). After this, *make sure* you use the actual pear.phpunit.de channel to install PHPUnit:

- sudo pear upgrade PEAR
- sudo pear config-set auto_discover 1
- sudo pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit

This has worked well for me ... hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

To get all the features of PHPUnit working you'll likely need to also do the following:

- sudo pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_MockObject

You'd think *--alldeps* would cover this but ...

**UPDATE 2**

> This method won't work with the current Ubuntu 11.10 because it
>   installs the broken pear installer 1.9.2 ...

Here's an alternative method given your continued issues using the go-pear.phar install method ...

- sudo apt-get install php-pear

Next, tell PEAR to update its own channel.

- sudo pear channel-update pear.php.net

Then, tell PEAR to upgrade itself to the newest version.

- sudo pear upgrade-all

Finally, install PHPUnit as proscribed above ...

- sudo pear config-set auto_discover 1
- sudo pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit

Comment: Recently i don't have any pear installation (i think) . Because when i tried to execute `pear` or `/usr/bin/pear` command. I'm getting error like *pear isn't installed* . And all other commands, you said returning an error. I said them before, in my question.

Comment: i just try install it again. While installing i set `/usr/bin` as my *Binaries directory* . After installation i got `** The 'pear' command is not currently in your PATH, so you need to
** use '/usr/bin/pear' until you have added
** '/usr/bin' to your PATH environment variable.` this notification. And then i'm executing `pear help` and `/usr/bin/pear help` commands but getting `pear iisn't installed` and `there is no file like usr/bin/pear` errors.

Comment: @Eray You just need to reference pear in your environment path somewhere. You can follow the instructions in this SO post to make that happen: [Ubuntu: How to link a binary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608496/ubuntu-how-to-link-a-binary)

Comment: there isn't pear file on /usr/bin

Comment: Oh, ok i misunderstood. BUt what should be content of this file ? Why it's automatically created when we install pear with phar ?

Comment: It *is* automatically created when you install with go-pear.phar. Your issue is making sure that wherever it's installed, it can be accessed from your path. So, if it's installed to `/home/eray/pear/bin/pear` as you mention in the comments to the other answer, you need to create a symlink in `/usr/bin` or `~/bin` to that file (wherever it was installed). For example: `ln -s /home/eray/pear/bin/ ~/bin` ... which is why I referenced [Ubuntu: How to link a binary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608496/ubuntu-how-to-link-a-binary) in my earlier comment.

Comment: Nothing more I can add ether. *maybe* removing /usr/lib/php5/ too just in case. All in all really solid an complete answer. definitely +1

Comment: I have tried them (with sudo) : `ln -s /home/eray/pear/bin/ ~/bin` , `ln -s /home/eray/pear/bin/ /usr/bin` . But still getting `pear isn't installed when tried this : 'pear help' or `pear version`

Comment: `locate /home/eray/pear/bin/pear` outputing *nothing* :) I'm really tired . I think  there isn't any pear installation on my machine. Because `require_once 'System.php';
var_dump(class_exists('System', false))` outputting just blank page, too.

Comment: @rdlowrey , http://screenr.com/385s :D On last screen i was trying to say : *BUt it say's `The 'pear' command is now at your service at /usr/bin/pear` * haha :)

Comment: Haha that's a little funny :) I'm going to update the answer with a different method to install pear. Hopefully this one won't leave you pulling your hair out ... now updated.

Comment: @rdlowrey `sudo apt-get install php5-pear` => `php5-pear` package couldn't located :D

Comment: @rdlowrey  `PEAR Version: 1.9.2
PHP Version: 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.3
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0
Running on: Linux eray-ubuntu 3.0.0-15-generic-pae #25-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 2 19:40:15 UTC 2012 i686
`

Comment: Okay, so it seems the only way it's going to work is to use the go-pear.phar installer. Remove the `apt-get php-pear` again and execute the go-pear.phar install steps. Even though the installer lies about /usr/bin/pear being at your service, it **must** be on the machine somewhere. Try a `locate pear` after the install and figure out where the binary executable was installed. It seems the only option is to figure out where it's located and create the appropriate symlink. Once you find the *actual* location of the executable, attempt to run it and see if you can get expected output from pear

Comment: How much of the comment stream can be cleaned up?  It looks like everything before @Eray comment about update 2 would be appropriate to be cleaned up.

Comment: @rdlowrey i found it ! It's `/usr/bin/pear~`

Comment: @rdlowrey , i was renamed it from `pear~` to `pear` :D Haha i'll undo it. And try it . and then i'll delete comments.

Comment: `pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit` => `bash: /usr/bin/pear there is no file` and `pear~ install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit` => `Could not open input file: /usr/share/php/pearcmd.php`

Comment: first, what does `pear -V` give you? Also, what output do you get for `locate pearcmd.php`?

Comment: (It name is `pear~` recently) . `pear~ -V` => `Could not open input file: /usr/share/php/pearcmd.php` AND `locate pearcmd.php` => nothing.

Comment: Okay, do you get anything from `pear~ config-get php_dir` ?

Comment: `pear~ config-get php_dir` => `Could not open input file: /usr/share/php/pearcmd.php`

Comment: Sometimes people have to restart the whole machine physically, probably due to PATH changes not propagating correctly. Before wasting hours and after you tried everything else, you might give that one a try and lemme know if that fixes it ...

Comment: Well perhaps it's possible that symlinks you created before are intercepting the pear command before it gets to /usr/bin/pear ??? you might check your *~/bin* directory to ensure there's nothing there to interfere as well as the */home/eray/pear/bin/pear* directory. Also, I would `rm /usr/bin/pear /usr/bin/pear~` and try the pear install again with go-pear once you know for sure that `/usr/bin/pear` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I got mine working by doing a [manual installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9007550/65387).

Comment: 1.9.4 (says at bottom of Q), but the manual installation shouldn't require any usage of pear.

Comment: i'm getting `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_TextUI_Command' not found in /usr/share/php/phpunit/phpunit.php on line 46` error.

Comment: @Eray: Does `phpunit` on it's own run, or do you get that error when you try to run your tests? I discovered I actually had an error in my test class, but `phpunit` itself was fine. Actually, I don't think your `phpunit.php` *should* contain a reference to that class...what's your phpunit.php look like?

Comment: I'm getting this error when i tried to launch just `phpunit` command. I'm not trying any php file.

Comment: @Eray: You sure you don't have some old phpunit code lying around? Try `which phpunit` and make sure it's running the right one.

Answer (score 1):

I've just upgraded my Ubuntu system and I've got PEAR 1.9.4 stable. Run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to get your Ubuntu synchronised and up to date.

If you were still struggling with the versions as above my suggestion is to install a previous version of PHP_CodeCoverage that is compatible with your phpunit. Before I upgraded my system, I had phpunit-3.5.15 (stable), PHP_CodeCoverage 1.0.5 (stable) installed with PEAR 1.9.2. If this is your phpunit version

```
sudo pear install PHP_CodeCoverage-1.0.5
```

should install PHP_CodeCoverage with PEAR 1.9.2.

I hope this helps and you get your unit tests running.