# Error when running PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, ubuntu-11.10

I get the following error when I try to run `phpunit .` from within my project's tests folder:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance() in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework.php on line 46
```

I installed PHPUnit via these commands:

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
sudo pear channel-discover components.ez.no
sudo pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

As none of the other methods seem to work, including `apt-get`.

I *think* CodeCoverage changed their singleton pattern at some point in time and hence removed `getInstance` but I don't know how to fix this error. How can I either downgrade CodeCoverage or upgrade PHPUnit?

I tried manually installing the latest versions of everything via the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install git
mkdir phpunit && cd phpunit
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/dbunit.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-file-iterator.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-text-template.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-token-stream.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-timer.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-story.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-invoker.git
sudo cp -r dbunit/PHPUnit /usr/share/php/
sudo cp -r php-code-coverage/PHP /usr/share/php/
sudo cp -r php-file-iterator/File /usr/share/php/
sudo cp -r php-invoker/PHP /usr/share/php/
sudo cp -r php-text-template/Text /usr/share/php/
sudo cp -r php-timer/PHP /usr/share/php/
sudo cp -r php-token-stream/PHP /usr/share/php/
sudo cp -r phpunit/PHPUnit /usr/share/php/
sudo cp -r phpunit-mock-objects/PHPUnit /usr/share/php/
sudo cp -r phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit /usr/share/php/
sudo cp -r phpunit-story/PHPUnit /usr/share/php/
sudo cp -r phpunit/phpunit.php /usr/share/php/
```

But that didn't help any. Now I just have a bunch of junk all over the place :\

---

Version info:

```
PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.3
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0
PHPUnit 3.6.9 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

---

```
Installed packages, channel pear.phpunit.de:
============================================
Package            Version State
File_Iterator      1.3.1   stable
PHPUnit            3.6.9   stable
PHPUnit_MockObject 1.1.1   stable
PHP_CodeCoverage   1.1.1   stable
PHP_Invoker        1.1.0   stable
PHP_Timer          1.0.2   stable
PHP_TokenStream    1.1.2   stable
Text_Template      1.1.1   stable
```

Comment: I haven't been able to get phpUnit to work for me either on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I have same problem and i already asked it with **50 points bounty** : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949963/phpunit-pear-upgrading-errors

Comment: Going on record as an opponent of PEAR, and the way PHPUnit is released in it's current state.

Comment: @MikePurcell: Well we don't have many alternatives for unit testing do we? That are easy to install and relatively easy to use? This project only has 2 unit tests so far...so we can still make the switch!

Comment: @Mark: PHPUnit works great for it's purpose, unit testing. I just disagree with the engineer's release strategies. I actually wrote my own custom autoloader, and bootstrapper, and got it to work without using PEAR. When I am finished with post I will link to you.

Comment: @MikePurcell: That would be great! You could save a lot of people some pain.

Comment: @Mark: Almost done with article, should be published tonight or tomorrow, when I do I will let you know here so you can check it out. You will be my beta tester :)

Comment: @Mark: Ok, done with v1.0 of the article, take a look at it and let me know if it works for you. Good luck! http://melikedev.com/2012/01/25/php-phpunit-use-phpunit-without-pear/

Answer (score 7):

you can try this, I have done it on my Ubuntu 12.04

1. sudo pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit
2. sudo pear uninstall pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_MockObject
3. sudo pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_MockObject
4. sudo pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit

I have tried many other methods. This works when I get the error blow.

> hegaofeng@ubuntu:~$ phpunit
>   PHP Warning:  require_once(PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Autoload.php): failed to open >?>stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 48
>   PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required >'PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Autoload.php' >(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on >line 48
>   hegaofeng@ubuntu:~$ cd /usr/share/php/

Answer (score 5):

I've had issues when not using the actual `pear.phpunit.de` channel to install PHPUnit, especially when trying to use a package manager like apt-get or yum. Try removing all the manually installed stuff you pulled from the git repository and do a `pear uninstall` of PHPUnit and its optional dependencies. Then:

- sudo pear upgrade PEAR
- sudo pear config-set auto_discover 1
- sudo pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit

This has worked for me ... hope it helps.

---

**UPDATE**

It probably goes without saying, but you should also purge your previous apt-get attempts as well before following the steps above:

- sudo apt-get purge php5-pear

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949963/phpunit-pear-upgrading-errors (**with 50 points bounty**)

Comment: Well that code me a different error: `PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Autoload.php'`

Comment: "MockObject" directory doesn't exist. Funny. You'd think "alldeps" would install all the deps. Apparently not. How do I get MockObjects back?

Comment: Almost forgot -- I had the same problem. I believe the correct command is: `pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject`. lemme know if that isn't correct. **OOPS** I think that should be `pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_MockObject`

Comment: `pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject` fails with "already installed" message...but the folder isn't there..hrm. Ok... uninstalled and reinstalled again, mocked objects intalled now, but now I get `Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Framework.php'` instead. There's a Framework folder, but no Framework.php

Comment: `No releases available for package "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_Framework"
`. The folder is already there though, just not `Framework.php`. I'm thinking it's a version mismatch and the files aren't in the same place.

Comment: So, the */usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/Framework* (or equivalent) directory is totally empty? Can you post the output of `pear list -c phpunit`?

Comment: @rdlowrey: No, there's plenty of files in it. Adding the output of that command to question.

Comment: @Mark When do you receive the `Failed opening required PHPUnit/Framework.php`? When you try to run the phpunit command? This is strange because on my working PHPUnit install with the same `pear list -c phpunit` output as yours I have no `Framework.php` file **anywhere** on my machine (as verified by `locate Framework.php`)

Comment: @rdlowrey: Yes...when running `phpunit .` in my tests folder. `which phpunit` gives me `/usr/bin/phpunit` and `tail /usr/bin/phpunit` gives me me some stuff about `Autoload.php`; no reference to Framework.php in there. Weird...would it be trying to autoload it from the wrong place? Or...everything is installed to `/usr/share/php/PHPUnit` not to `/usr/share/pear` -- `/usr/share/pear` doesn't exist though..so it shouldn't be looking there..? I don't know what it's trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

## Manual Installation for Ubuntu 11.10

```
mkdir phpunit && cd phpunit
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/dbunit.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-file-iterator.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-text-template.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-token-stream.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-timer.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-story.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-invoker.git
cd phpunit && git checkout 3.6 && cd ..
cd dbunit && git checkout 1.1 && cd ..
cd php-code-coverage && git checkout 1.1 && cd ..
cd phpunit-mock-objects && git checkout 1.1 && cd ..
cd phpunit-selenium && git checkout 1.1 && cd ..
sudo mv ./* /usr/share/php/
ln -s /usr/share/php/phpunit/phpunit.php ~/bin/phpunit
gksudo gedit /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Add the following to your `include_path`:

```
/usr/share/php/dbunit:/usr/share/php/php-code-coverage:/usr/share/php/php-file-iterator:/usr/share/php/php-text-template:/usr/share/php/php-timer:/usr/share/php/php-token-stream:/usr/share/php/phpunit:/usr/share/php/phpunit-mock-objects:/usr/share/php/phpunit-selenium:/usr/share/php/phpunit-story:/usr/share/php/php-invoker
```

Answer (score 1):

Open **/usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework.php** and you will see this:

```
trigger_error(
    'Please no longer include "PHPUnit/Framework.php".', E_USER_NOTICE
);
```

That's all! **Please no longer include "PHPUnit/Framework.php"!!!**

Answer (score 1):

Before installing PHPUnit on your system, clear pear's cache

```
pear clear-cache
```

From what i have seen, maybe you haven't integrated PHPUnit with your project. You don't need to only install PHPUnit using PEAR, i believe the files you need are not in the project.