# Error: Class 'SebastianBergmann\Version' not found in cakePHP's PHPunit

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, testing, phpunit

I guess this is not a question but when you install PHPunit for the cakePHP framework you may encounter this strange error:

```
Error: Class 'SebastianBergmann\Version' not found  
File: /var/www/clients/client0/web29/web/app/Vendor/PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php  
Line: 70
```

This causes the unit testing not to work. When you go to /app/Vendor/PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php you can edit the *public static function id* method and just replace it with *return '3.8';*

I'm not sure if it's the right way but at least it seems to work. And I think the installation of phpunit can be problematic so also check this: [Error when running PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991620/error-when-running-phpunit)

Comment: What PHP version is that, and which phpunit version? Which cake version?

Answer (score 1):

PHPUnit 3.8 is not released and far from stable.

I wouldn't suggest using it but using the released 3.7 branch.

Your folder structure suggest that you are using composer to install PHPUnit? In that case make sure you are requiring `stable` releases or, if you can't to that for other reasons, put the PHPUnit version to `3.7.*`.

The composer install issue with current `master` will be solved soon but if you don't have a very good reason for running 3.8 now i would suggest against it strongly (as it is going to break again).